# Pass array to varargs function in php

Tags: php, php-7, variadic-functions

I've got a varargs type method defined in PHP 7

```php
function selectAll(string $sql, ...$params) { }
```

The problem I'm running into is that sometimes I want to call this method when I already have an array, and I can't just directly pass an array variable to this method.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use splat operator to unpack the array arguments just like you used in the function:

```
selectAll($str, ...$arr);
```

So like this:

```
function selectAll(string $sql, ...$params) { 
    print_r(func_get_args());
}

$str = "This is a string";
$arr = ["First Element", "Second Element", 3];

selectAll($str, ...$arr);
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a string
    [1] => First Element
    [2] => Second Element
    [3] => 3
)
```

[Eval](https://eval.in/725913) for this.

---

If you don't use splat operator in arguments, you will end up [like this](https://eval.in/725916)